# Binding several views to a Listener with multiple methods in Butterknife

Tags: android, data-binding, android-edittext, butterknife

I'm using Butterknife(8.4.0) to instantiate my views in a fragment that has several EditTexts.

I'm using these EditTexts to set a string to a specific Model attribute. I don't want to create loads of bind methods for each Edittext so on `@onTextChanged` I pass in all the edit texts. I'm only interested in `AfterTextChanged()` so I've also passed that in. I then use the editText ids to specify which model attribute should be set.

```
@BindView(R.id.edit_text_one) EditText textFieldOne;
@BindView(R.id.edit_text_two) EditText textFieldTwo;

@OnTextChanged(value = {R.id.edit_text_one, R.id.edit_text_two}, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
    void setEditTextFields(EditText editText, Editable editable) {
        switch (editText.getId()) {
            case R.id.edit_text_one:
                myModel.setStringOne(editable.toString());
                break;
            case R.id.edit_text_two:
                myModel.setStringTwo(editable.toString());
                break;
        }
    }
```

However I'm getting a compile error

```
Error:(117, 10) error: @OnTextChanged methods can have at most 1 parameter(s). (com.skeeno.android.gamecabinet.Fragment.EditorFragment.setEditTextFields)
```

I've read [here](http://craftedcourses.io/all-about-butter-knife-part-3/) that you just pass in the view as the first argument but that doesn't seem to work since AfterTextChanged is only expecting an editable.

Is there a way to do this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: After looking further into the tutorial that was linked in the OP. That way is  impossible.

Comment: Hey so, we can't use it like this? I'm facing the same problem but I seem to only be able to pass the `Editable`. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Passing View with **@onTextChanged** is not possible currently. I tried too.

However, below code can be used to get the current view,

*//Inside a fragment*

***View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();***

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit late but if anyone will have this issue, answer can be helpful therefore, here how i make it work. You cannot send two parameter method for `AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED` therefore; you need to change method  `void setEditTextFields(EditText editText, Editable editable)` to `void setEditTextFields(Editable editable)`. In this case you need to write `@OnTextChanged` for all `EditText` you want to listen.
Here is final code should be;

```
@BindView(R.id.edit_text_one) EditText textFieldOne;
@BindView(R.id.edit_text_two) EditText textFieldTwo;

@OnTextChanged(value =R.id.edit_text_one, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
void edit_text_oneChanged(Editable editable) {
    myModel.setStringOne(editable.toString());
}


@OnTextChanged(value =R.id.edit_text_two, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
void edit_text_twoChanged(Editable editable) {
    myModel.setStringTwo(editable.toString());
}
```